# Where is the Architecture Menu in Visual Studio 2012 Premium?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I can't seem to access the Architecture Tools available in Visual Studio 2012 Premium `Version 11.0.60610.01 Update 4` using `.Net Version 4.5.50709`

My only visible menu options on startup are:

- FILE
- EDIT
- VIEW
- DEBUG
- TEAM
- SQL
- TOOLS
- TEST
- ANALYZE
- WINDOW
- HELP

And with a project open these two extra items appear:

- PROJECT
- BUILD

There is nothing under the any of the menus related to `Architecture Tools` except for

```
VIEW > Toolbars > Architecture Designers
```

The Architecture Designers toobar's buttons are all grayed out when enabled.

---

Do I need to do something extra after the Visual Studio 2012 install to make them show up?

Does it only work for certain types of projects (I am trying to make an MVC4 project)? Does it have to be enabled on a per-project basis?

Is there a difference between how the Architecture tools work in Premium vs Ultimate?

Answer (score 6):

Isn't it only available in VS 2012 Ultimate? (which used to be called "Architecture Edition".)

Comment: can u verify with link?

Comment: Well, I myself have the Ultimate version installed, and the Architecture menu is present. Another developer next to me has the Premium, and he's never seen this item in his version.  See the last item in this comparison matrix that deals with architecture diagrams: http://www.microway.com.au/microsoft/visual-studio-2012-compare-editions.php

Comment: here it says there are read only access to the tools. What does that mean? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio

Comment: That would mean that Premium can open architecture diagrams for viewing, but it won't be able to modify them or generate new ones.

Comment: For anyone interested, here's the feature grid between different Visual Studio editions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Editions_feature_grid

Comment: Updated direct link to feature grid: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Feature_grid